# Will the torque applied to a circular object be the same if the object isn't aligned in the center of the Torque?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, torque, force-measurement

I'm a student designing a system to automatically turn a steering wheel.
In this design the motor will be in the center of the steering wheel and it will apply it's torque on the steering wheel through clamps.
Will the force exerted on the steering wheel change when the motor is slightly off-center (2cm max) or will this not matter? I've debated with friends and we can't seem to get a clear answer.

Comment: A driven wheels, and especially gears, are just round levers. Or an infinite number of levers positioned around a center. An off-center or mishapen wheel means these levers aren't all equal length. What does that tell you?

Comment: I suggest showing your design for others to comment on. Your description lacks clarity.

Comment: applied torque is the same no matter what you apply it to ... it is the resulting force on the steering wheel column that may change ... applied torque does not necessarily result in motion

Answer (score 1):

No, you can have your motor even outside of the steering wheel and connect it to the center of the steering wheel by a pulley. it doesn't matter.

Torque does not have a center. It has direction and magnitude. It is the cross product of force vector and lever vector. and it points out of the plane of those two vectors.

The only loss would be friction loss in the pulley or the links.

Comment: torque doesn't have a center, but to make the wheel move it has to be about the wheel's axis, otherwise it's a torque that doesn't turn the wheel.  You can't twist the rim of a steering wheel to turn it.

Comment: many times when i tried to change a flat tire i had lowered to make it stop rotating by the torque of the tire wrench, it would make an effort to roll the tire on the ground while the nut is neither coaxial with the axel or center of interface of the ground snd tire.

Comment: @TigerGuy Of course I can turn the wheel just by applying a torque the the rim. If the input axis doesn't move, you have a gear or friction drive. If the input axis follows the rim, then it is a swing-arm transmission.

Answer (score 0):

For constant rotational force on the steering wheel, the shaft to the motor connection will experience the varying magnitude of shear stresses around its circumference and resulting in more tear and wear.

[image]